# Can't connect to onion sites "hidden service is unavailable"

Tags: onion-services, help

Everything is fine and Tor check displays "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor." but I can't access any onion sites. please help!

```
15/11/2014 15:23:01 p.m..970 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
15/11/2014 15:23:01 p.m..972 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
15/11/2014 15:23:02 p.m..233 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
15/11/2014 15:23:02 p.m..659 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
15/11/2014 15:23:02 p.m..660 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
15/11/2014 16:23:09 p.m..253 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 3598 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
15/11/2014 16:23:09 p.m..253 [NOTICE] Tried for 3608 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
15/11/2014 16:23:10 p.m..451 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors 
15/11/2014 16:23:11 p.m..293 [NOTICE] We now have enough directory information to build circuits. 
15/11/2014 16:23:11 p.m..294 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
15/11/2014 16:23:11 p.m..294 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
15/11/2014 16:23:12 p.m..287 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
15/11/2014 16:23:12 p.m..287 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
15/11/2014 16:23:15 p.m..449 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
15/11/2014 16:23:53 p.m..900 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please clarify why your question is different from the other similar questions that have been popping up recently (there are a lot of them). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 15/11/2014 16:23:09 p.m..253 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 3598 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work.
>   15/11/2014 16:23:09 p.m..253 [NOTICE] Tried for 3608 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)

These indicate that your internal clock is off by 1 hour. Probably a time zone thing or a daylight saving thing. Altho it does seem to establish a circuit and successfully bootstrap, having your clock off is not good. Fixing that will likely solve your issue.

If not, here is a service where you can check whether an onion is down just for you or for everyone. (I guess 'everyone' means: the host this checking service runs on..)

> https://onionup.com/ (clearnet)
>   http://onionuptst6up7n2.onion/ (Tor net)

If you get your links from an outdated or poorly maintained list, it's possible that many of them are in fact down.